# Swipe function to materializecss tabs

Tags: tabs, swipe, materialize

So, I am using materializecss for a web development.

There is a tab functionality however it does not support swipe function yet on mobile like a native android app.

Does anyone know how I can implement swipe functionality to it? How difficult would this be?

For example, here is the demo content:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
    <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
    <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
    <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

I still didn't see this in the official materializecss demo so for everyones future benefit:

```
$('#tabs-swipe-demo').tabs({ 'swipeable': true });
```

Comment: adding this ruins the Desktop view.

Comment: @MohammedShamshid Yes, for me too! Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

CSS add:

```
.carousel .carousel-item{
    width:100%;
}
```

JS add:

```
$('ul.tabs').tabs({
  swipeable : true,
  responsiveThreshold : Infinity
});
```

```js
$('ul.tabs').tabs({
  swipeable: true,
  responsiveThreshold: Infinity
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<style>
.carousel .carousel-item {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>

<ul id="tabs-swipe-demo" class="tabs">
  <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#swipe-1">Test 1</a></li>
  <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#swipe-2">Test 2</a></li>
  <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#swipe-3">Test 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="swipe-1" class="col s12 blue">First tab content</div>
<div id="swipe-2" class="col s12 red">Second tab content</div>
<div id="swipe-3" class="col s12 green">Third tab content</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin

```
    $(function() {
  $("#test").swipe( {
    //Generic swipe handler for all directions
    swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
      $(this).text("You swiped " + direction );  
    }
  });

  //Set some options later
  $("#test").swipe( {fingers:2} );
});
```

Enjoy!

ps. check: http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Basic_swipe.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you should include this line in your js.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.tabs').tabs({swipeable: true});
});
```